# Script to execute arbitrary command on each Git project in a directory

Tags: bash, shell, git

The idea is simple, most people have some one directory containing all their projects as subdirectories. When you are in the top directory and you run this script like so `for-each-git.sh git status` it will run the command `git status` in each of the folders. I have another script called `git-ffwd` that fetches all remotes and fast forward updates them which I usually run each morning with this script.

```
#!/bin/bash
for dir in $(find . -maxdepth 1 -type d); do
    (
        cd ${dir}
        if [ -d ".git" ]; then
            pwd
            "$@"
            echo
        fi
    )
done
```

Some explanation:

- The parenthesis is so we are able to easily go back to the project directory in case the commands you push in run `cd` or something. (It makes a subshell.)
- `pwd` is so we know for sure which directory is being worked on and the `echo` is just so a new line separates everything a little more.

I know this is a small script but I am new-ish to writing Bash scripts and want to learn.

The lines `pwd; "$@"; echo` seem a little ugly, though they do work. Also I can't pass multiple commands in with a `;` like `echo hey; echo bye` because the `;` ends the statement in the `"$@"` line, so I am wondering if there's a better way to write that line (or pass them in).

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `find` and testing whether `.git` is a directory, you could make a simplification:

```
for git_dir in */.git ; do
(
    cd "$git_dir/.." &&
    pwd &&
    $@
    echo
)
done
```

Admittedly, this causes an error when `.git` exists but is not a directory:

> ```
> -bash: cd: blah/.git/..: Not a directory
> ```

… instead of silently skipping that entry as your script does.  But I would consider the error message to be a feature, not a bug.  =)  Note my use of `&&` after `cd` to ensure that the command is not executed if the `cd` fails.  (That could happen if the directory lacks the executable bit.)

If you wanted to support compound commands like `echo hey; echo bye`, you could use `eval $@`.  Using `eval` feels a bit risky, but it's OK if the script is for your own personal use and won't be attacked.

Comment: Why is eval risky? I understand what you mean about personal use but I don't get why `$@` is less dangerous than `eval $@`.